# selecting a specific string from blob column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob

I have a table named as MSTCUSTOMERPROFILE haves a column ROLELIST which is of BLOB type. Now this BLOB haves data in xml format eg data...

```
<RoleListDTO>
  <rolelist>
    <RoleDTO>
      <idEntity/>
      <idEntityDesc/>
      <userType>ECU</userType>
      <userTypeDesc/>
      <idRole>5</idRole>
      <description>02A ENQUIRIES - ACCOUNT INFORMATION</description>
      <idChannel>01</idChannel>
      <idChannelDesc/>
      <token/>
      <datCreated/>
      <createdBy/>
      <datLastUpdated/>
      <isDefaultRole>false</isDefaultRole>
      <isDisplayCustProfile>false</isDisplayCustProfile>
      <idcust/>
      <typecust/>
      <roleCreatebyUser>
        <ListUserDTO>
          <idEntity/>
          <idEntityDesc/>
          <userType/>
          <userTypeDesc/>
          <idChannel/>
          <idChannelGroup/>
          <idChannelDesc/>
          <firstName/>
          <lastName/>
          <idChannelUser/>
          <salutation/>
          <idUser/>
          <email/>
          <isActive/>
          <isProxyLocked/>
          <isGroupFlag/>
          <lockReason/>
          <actDeactReason/>
        </ListUserDTO>
      </roleCreatebyUser>
    </RoleDTO>
    <RoleDTO>
      <idEntity/>
      <idEntityDesc/>
      <userType>ECU</userType>
      <userTypeDesc/>
      <idRole>88</idRole>
      <description>02C ENQUIRIES - CREDIT CARD DETAILS</description>
      <idChannel>01</idChannel>
      <idChannelDesc/>
      <token/>
      <datCreated/>
      <createdBy/>
      <datLastUpdated/>
      <isDefaultRole>false</isDefaultRole>
      <isDisplayCustProfile>false</isDisplayCustProfile>
      <idcust/>
      <typecust/>
      <roleCreatebyUser>
        <ListUserDTO>
          <idEntity/>
          <idEntityDesc/>
          <userType/>
          <userTypeDesc/>
          <idChannel/>
          <idChannelGroup/>
          <idChannelDesc/>
          <firstName/>
          <lastName/>
          <idChannelUser/>
          <salutation/>
          <idUser/>
          <email/>
          <isActive/>
          <isProxyLocked/>
          <isGroupFlag/>
          <lockReason/>
          <actDeactReason/>
        </ListUserDTO>
      </roleCreatebyUser>
    </RoleDTO>
  </rolelist>
  <rmemail/>
</RoleListDTO>
```

I want to fetch the data inside `<idRole>` tag in the blob, in this case it being 88 i.e the result I want to fetch.

I need to do this by select query, is it possible in Oracle Database.? How ??

Comment: No one can answer if the xml will not be readable format..Please format

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XML functions doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#SQLRF51184

Something like EXTRACTVALUE

Comment: While this may partially answer the question it does not fully answer it and is almost a link-only answer.

Comment: MT0 yeah, plus that is for XML type I want it for BLOB

Answer (score 0):

I have had a work around basically I wanted to do some logic based on a value in node in xml which happens to be inside this blob and wanted it in java. so I read the blob in java, into an byte array, made a DTO, a java class exactly with the same details and properties as the xml and nodes in it and populated it by using DTO unmarshalling logic, passed byte array and all.

So basically I did a workaround and its exactly not the answer I was looking for but it works.